# Images in wx.ListControl are cut off

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wx.ListCtrl in REPORT mode and i use an image list to display icons which are 50x50 pixels with SetItemColumnImage. The problem now is that the text I display in the column right of the icon is less than 50 pixels high and the parts of the icons that are higher than the text are cut off.

Is there a way to tell ListCtrl to adjust the row height to the height of the icons? Last refuge would be to change the fontsize of the text, but there should be a better way.

**Update:**

Here is some of my code:

```
self.list = util.ListCtrl(nb, style=wx.LC_REPORT|
                wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL|wx.LC_NO_HEADER|wx.LC_ALIGN_LEFT)
self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'Avatar', width=-1)
self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'Name', width=-1)
self.list.SetColumnWidth(0, 50)

self.imagelist = wx.ImageList(50, 50, 255, 20)
self.list.SetImageList(self.imagelist, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL)

i = 0
for user in self.users:
    self.list.Append(['', user['name']])

    if user['avatar']:
        bitmap = wx.BitmapFromImage(user['avatar'])
        imageidx = self.imagelist.Add(bitmap)
        self.list.SetItemColumnImage(i, 0, imageidx)

    i += 1
```

When I remove the LC_REPORT flag the images are completely visible but they are all displayed in one row and the names aren't visible anymore.

Comment: Could you show us some of your code? Does it display properly without the REPORT flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the images are 50x50, I don't think they qualify as "small" any more. Try using the wx.IMAGE_LIST_NORMAL instead of wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL. I can't find anything about manually setting row height, so I'm guessing that's not possible. However, I did find a [bug report](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/12806) on this topic that says it was resolved in wx2.9. Are you using 2.9?

Alternatively, you could use the UltimateListCtrl which is pure Python and if it doesn't have that ability, you can probably get it patched quickly as the author is very responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a couple cups of coffee to figure it out.

The call to ImageList.Add should **precede** ListCtrl.Append (or ListCtrl.InsertItem) in order for the ListCtrl to change the height of its rows according to the height of images in ImageList.

So instead of

```
for user in self.users:
    self.list.Append(['', user['name']])

    if user['avatar']:
        bitmap = wx.BitmapFromImage(user['avatar'])
        imageidx = self.imagelist.Add(bitmap)
        self.list.SetItemColumnImage(i, 0, imageidx)
```

You should go with something like this

```
for user in self.users:

    if user['avatar']:
        bitmap = wx.BitmapFromImage(user['avatar'])
        imageidx = self.imagelist.Add(bitmap)

    self.list.Append(['', user['name']])

    if user['avatar']:
        self.list.SetItemColumnImage(i, 0, imageidx)
```

Which looks ugly, until you implement a default avatar:

```
def_avatar = 'default_avatar.jpg'

for user in self.users:

    bitmap = wx.BitmapFromImage(user['avatar'] if user['avatar'] else def_avatar)
    imageidx = self.imagelist.Add(bitmap)

    self.list.Append(['', user['name']])
    self.list.SetItemColumnImage(i, 0, imageidx)
```